# XCode4 does not produces archives. At all

Tags: xcode4, distribution, archive, testflight

I am attempting to create my first ever app to be tested/deployed via:

- XCode 4.0.1
- TestFlight

I cannot get archive to actually produce an archive in XCode.

It always says it has succeeded in building the archive (see image), but I cannot find it in the Organiser and it doesn't appear in Finder either.

[image: Archive successfully built?]

I am doing it for Ad Hoc distribution as per TestFlight instructions for Xcode4

I have done the following.

> 1. Created development certificate for the app
> 2. Created app ID for the app
> 3. Assigned a device The green lights appear for Enabled for
>      development and Enabled for Production, and Game Center / In App
>      Purchase are active/green.
> 4. Created a development provisioning profile
> 5. Downloaded all provisioning profiles.
> 6. I can launch the app successfully in my device.

Now we get onto distribution.

> 1. In certificates, created a 'Current Distribution Certificate' for
>      the app
> 2. In provision, created a 'Distribution profile' where 'Ad hoc' is
>      selected, the app id is selected and the device is selected

Now we get onto following the TestFlight instructions for XCode4

I can do everything except the last part,

> Archiving and Packaging
>   1. Select the iOS Device option in the Schemes drop-down
>
> 2. Under the Product menu, select Archive
> 3. In the Organizer window that appears (go to Window -> Organizer if
>      it does not), select Archives at the top, your application on the
>      left, and the most recent archive at the bottom, and click Share

It simply does not list/show or apparently create the archive.

- I ensured that the archive and all adhoc setup is as the instructions say.
- I clean the product, save it as a workspace (this is not in the TestFlight docs, but in Apple's docs), and verify again that it will deploy in the device.

But when I try to archive it, no archive ever appears.

I have no idea how to solve this, its really annoying.

One video I've seen shows a guy click "Enable entitlements", but I cannot find this option -- is this only in the latest Xcode?

There must be an easier way to do all this!

Any help on this would be very useful.

Edits:
I have a video of the process I have taken, if people are interested.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
I can find no video that documents this specific process.

A full breakdown of the exact steps I do and use;

> ### Steps @date: 05-10-2011
>
> Sidebar: Certificates > [Distribution tab]
>
> 1. Clicked Request certificate button
> 2. Generate CSR with keychain     Online certificate status protocol =
>      off   Certificate revocation list = off
>
>    a. Request CSR from Certifcate Authority    b. Enter credentials
>      EXACTLY as they are when I signed up to Apple     c. Keysize = 2048,
>      Algorithm = RSA
> 3. Upload this CSR via "Choose file" button & submit
> 4. Download 'distribution_identity.cer'
> 5. Double click, it say "Do you want to add the certificate from the
>      file 'distribution_identify.cer' to a keychain?" with "login"
>      selected.  I press OK.
>
> Sidebar: Provisioning > [Distribution provisioning tab]
>
> 1. Click new profile
> 2. Select 'Ad hoc'
> 3. Enter profile name of "{name of app profile}"
> 4. Select App ID of "helloWorld_3oct"
> 5. Select iPod to distribute to. Note: it says "the final application
>      will run only on these selected devices." Note: Not sure if I'm meant
>      to say "Yes" but I do anyway.
> 6. Distribution provisioning profile is now created.
> 7. Download the "{nameofapp}.mobileprovision"
> 8. Double click on it.
> 9. It now appears in the organizer
> 10. Close organizer.
> 11. Open project.
> 12. Add icon and icon@2x.png to project. They appear in .plist file
>       for the project They also appear under Targets > Summary
> 13. Under project > info
>
> a. Create duplicate release configuration b. Name it "Ad Hoc"
>
> 14. Under project > build settings
>
> a. Make sure everything is set under "iPhone distribution (Amarjit
>   Deo)" no codes appear in this title. ie: In the development one there
>   is a code in brackets next to the name.
>
> 15. Under targets > build settings
>
> a. Change code signing identity to "iPhone distribution (Amarjit Deo)"
>   no codes appear in this title.
>
> 16. Go to Edit Schemes.
> 17. In Archive select Build configuration to be "Ad Hoc"
> 18. Press "OK"
> 19. Make sure "iOS device" is selected (it is not plugged in)
> 20. Run Product > Clean
> 21. Run Product > Archive.
>
> No errors. Success is reported.
>
> Go to organizer.
>
> No product archives exist at all in the organizer.
>
> 22. Try doing skip install trick  Tried Yes/No/Yes combination for
>       both product & target, then Product > Archive = No archive    Tried all
>       permutations, still no joy.

Comment: I have upgraded to XCode4.1 and still no joy.  I might try and do a simple hello world application and see if that works instead.

Comment: I have decided to start the whole process again from scratch, clearing out all keys/chains, etc.  Maybe this will solve the problem.

Comment: I've been unable to create archives after flushing out all keychains. Tried re-installing xcode, tried doing everything twice, thrice. Its really, really getting annoying.

Comment: Tried installing, this did not solve the problem.  Tried clearing out build target directory, tried saying no to skip-install on Project but yes on Target (and vise versa); still no archives.  I can only assume XCode did not download properly and will try to do something about it tomorrow

Comment: I have a video of my procedure if people are interested.  Right now, I'm concentrating on other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue now!

Okay, it turns out either XCode was corrupted in download or was conflicting with earlier builds (Even if you uninstall it for some odd reason).

Here's what I did.

1) Re-downloaded XCode (via a better/faster connected line, ie: University)

2) Used

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

To uninstall Xcode.

3) Removed all references to XCode that I could find.

For some reason Xcode installed in Developer and Developer (null) so both these folders I deleted.

4) Checked existence of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives and deleted this folder

5) Cleared out all keychain certificates and re-downloaded all required certificates, including the ones at this address

http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

6) Went through the entire process with a fine tooth comb, ensured and double checked everything.

7) Got an archive for a simple app!

Picture included.

Thank goodness for that.  I'm backing up my computer and all these files and I'm going onto the next stage, TestFlight!

[image]